# NodeJS: How to add a HTML value (taken from a JSON file) on the webpage?

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

I've some HTML values in a JSON file. I want to display that HTML on my website in text format, not in HTML format.

I'm fetching HTML data from a JSON file and using Nunjuck Template to display it on web page but instead of text format, it get showed up in HTML format like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
const JSONFile = require('../public/blog.json');
.
.
.
router.get('/:post', function (req, res) {
        const path = req.params.post;
        const json = JSONFile[path];
        const content2 = json.content;
        res.render('blogs.njk', {
                content: content2,
        });
});
```

I had even tried using [node-html-to-text](https://github.com/werk85/node-html-to-text) but later realized that it's mainly for changing email formats which don't work on my blogging site.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the safe-filter in your nunjucks-template.

```
{{ content | safe }}
```

Make sure you are protected against XSS-attacks, which become possible when using the safe-filter. Watch closely where you fetch your HTML from.

Comment: Great. It worked. had added the global configuration of nunjuck >>> nunjucks.configure('views', {autoescape: false,}); Can you throw some more  light on XSS attack?

Comment: If this solved your problem, consider accepting it as an answer. XSS attacks are attacks where HTML gets injected into the browser. If your JSON contains a <script>-tag with "malicious" code inside it, then it will get executed when you insert it into the DOM like this. So if you serve user input, you should escape it, so that users cannot enter <script>-tags or something like that.